# How to insert a string into a script tag?

Tags: javascript

I have been using XMLHttpRequest to load my javascript file and insert it into the the head of my html file. I have tried:

```
var headNode = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var js = document.createElement("script");
js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = this.url.replace(project.basePath,'');
headNode.appendChild(js);
```

This works but i have a timing problem when i do it this way, so no function can be called. I am now trying another way, where i can get the string of codes from the js file and insert it into the head, when i do it this way it clears my html and only adds the new code in.

```
var code= this.ajaxRequest.responseText;
script.write('<script>'+code+'</script>')
```

is there away to append it to the head for example (this doesn't work);

```
var code= this.ajaxRequest.responseText;
var headNode = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.write('<script>'+code+'</script>')
headNode.append(script)
```

Thanks for the help in advance. p.s I am not using jquery.

Comment: what kind of timing problem?

Comment: document.write(  '<script'+' src="http://'+'www.example.com/myScript.js"></scri'+'pt>')      is what we use. It seams to work well, but I dont know if it will solve your issue

Comment: I was bitten by what I assume to be your "timing" problem in FF2 times. Solved it declaring `var includesLoaded=0;` in the original HTML, then having the last statement in the include be `includesLoaded++` and polling for value with `setInterval()`. Hacky, but was the only thing that worked cross-browser then.

Comment: Jdahern: sorry about that i meant 
var code= this.ajaxRequest.responseText;
document.write('<script>'+code+'</script>') for the second part. That clears the entire html and only adds the new code in.
Eugen: yeah that is who i managed to get around it but I also believe it is hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach you tried failed because XmlHttpRequest (also called an ajax request)  is asynchronous.

So by the time your script gets loaded, your other scrip tags code get executed (before the script file is load).

You could fix this issue, by using event handling in javascript.
You can create a custom event called 'loaded' and dispatch it.

And in your other script tag that contains code, add an event listener for the same event.

And in the event handling or the event listener function,  call the required functions that you want to execute after the script gets loaded.

Your second approach fails because document.write or document.append  over-writes the document if it is used after  the html page is rendered.

So using this functions after the page has displayed should be avoided.

P.S - Sorry that I could not give any demo code as I am answering this from my cell phone.

Comment: Thank you really helpful and well explained. I solved it by adding a loaded dispatch. Would i still need XmlHttpRequest if i was to run it on a server (not local server and i don't have a server to test this) to retrieve the js files?

Comment: First of all I want to know, what is the need of loading js file within the script tags, I mean dynamically?

Comment: I have a bootup.js which checks what setup js file i want to use depending on the user clicked. I have an abstract setup. so if the user clicked on setup1 for example that will run setup1 asbtract setup. if the user clicked on setup2 that will run setup2 and abstract. the abstract stays the same but the setup is different. I hope i explained it clearly for you :)

Comment: oh sorry mystic i read the question wrong then. I wanted to load setup .js depending on what the user click on.

Comment: I am pretty much clear now why you want to load it dynamically.

You will require to use XMLHttpRequest for loading the files on server as well.

To simplify loading javascript files asynchronously, you can try using [RequreJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html).
This is a very useful library and personally I like it and use it too.

Another way is without using XMLHttpRequest, i.e. you can include those files in the html with the script(src) itself directly and call functions according to your need. But this can be a problem if functions with same name are in both files.

Comment: Thank you i will have a lot and implement that in :D

Comment: look and implement that in*

Comment: Go ahead. All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

JS parser error on your < /script> in code.

try

```
var code= this.ajaxRequest.responseText;
script.write('<script>'+code+'</scr'+'ipt>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just eval() the response text?

Comment: Nothing came up on it :(

Comment: I think i read up somewhere that i should not use eval() because "it is dangerous". I cant remember the reason.